# How to enable WebP upload to a custom form's managed_file input

Tags: forms

This question is not about image styles, which are all already configured to accept WebP.
Our theme uses a custom form with elements like

```c
$form['cta1']['fp_cta1_background'] = [
    '#type'              => 'managed_file',
    '#upload_validators' => array( 'file_validate_is_image' => array() ),
    '#upload_location'   => 'public://images/',
    '#title'             => t( 'Ozadje' ),
    '#default_value'     => theme_get_setting( 'fp_cta1_background' ),
];
```

Now, the server has GD installed and it's what Drupal (9.5) is using. And when I checked what `file_validate_is_image` resolves to for GD, it's as expected in local code as well — it explicitly supports WebP.

Yet when trying to upload to this form, I nonetheless get the error:

```
The specified file blabla.webp could not be uploaded.

Only files with the following extensions are allowed: 
   jpg jpeg gif png txt doc xls pdf ppt pps odt ods odp.
```

**Any ideas what's going on?**

PS: I know I could override or even skip that validator with things like this, but it would be repetitive and I'd rather get to the bottom of the original problem if possible:

```c
'#upload_validators' => array(
    'file_validate_extensions' => array('png gif jpg jpeg webp'),
    'file_validate_size' => array(300000),
    'file_validate_image_resolution' => array('800x600', '400x300'),
  ),
```

Comment: Tag the Question with the Drupal major version.

Comment: The version tags specifically instruct to tag only version-specific questions @cilefen

Comment: WebP support differs by version, so this will get different answers by version. We'll guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Drupal 9.5 this list of allowed extensions comes from https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/9.5.10/core/modules/file/src/Upload/FileUploadHandler.php#L35

```
/**
 * The default extensions if none are provided.
 */
const DEFAULT_EXTENSIONS = 'jpg jpeg gif png txt doc xls pdf ppt pps odt ods odp';
```

This is used in https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/0918c86fce10885c7b657a9aa2116b16981d3f8b/core/modules/file/src/Upload/FileUploadHandler.php#L323 if no extension validator is set, so it looks like you need to specify it each time indeed.

**Update**: Core issue: [Allow user-uploaded WebP images everywhere in Drupal by default: image fields, media library, text editors](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3282679)

Comment: That's it, thanks. The code is the same on master, but there's already an issue for adding WebP to all the missing places like this.

Comment: I have added the core issue to the answer.